# Replicate iOS contact button from Mail

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

I am making a custom email client and I want to capture some of the look and feel established by other existing clients. I want to make a button that looks like the little bubble that displays a contact name in the default mail app as well as apps like Mailbox.

[image: iOS Contact Bubble]

Does anyone know the best way to render a UIView or UIButton like this? Should I just sample the color and change the alpha value and then round the corners using something like:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = someRadiusThatMakesItRound;
button.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

and then set the border color of the view
Alternatively, I could just make an image template and stretch it, but ideally there is a way to render it natively with some UIKit stuff.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would subclass the button or view and then override the init and drawRect methods.  Here's an example of UIView I subclassed.

```
#import "CustomSectionView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface CustomSectionView () {
    UIColor *headerColor;
    UIColor *linesColor;
}

@end

@implementation CustomSectionView

@synthesize titleLabel;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        headerColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        linesColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        //title label
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 3, 110, 18)];
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Bold" size:15];
        [self addSubview:titleLabel];

    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame headerColor:(UIColor *)color linesColor:(UIColor *)color1
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        if (color == nil) {
            color = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
        headerColor = color;

        if (color1 == nil) {
            color1 = [UIColor clearColor];
        }
        linesColor = color1;

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        //title label
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 3, 110, 18)];
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Bold" size:15];
        [self addSubview:titleLabel];

    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, linesColor.CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, linesColor.CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width,25);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, headerColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I knew that this route was an option, but I think I was just trying to see if there was a better/simpler and more elegant solution to the issue